# Grouping by month and year

Tags: r

I assume this is a very simple transformation but I'm unable to get it right:

I have two columns in a data table. One contains the date and the other contains some unique numbers. I basically what the count of rows in a particular month and year.

I want to know the number of readings in 2011-02,then number of readings in 2011-03 and so on and so forth.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: give us your data frame.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's some free data:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(
    x = sample(Sys.Date()-0:120, 20, TRUE),
    y = sample(100, 20, TRUE)
)
```

We can do this quite easily with *data.table* by using a reformatted date in the `by` argument.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(N = .N), by = .(month = format(x, "%Y-%m"))]
#      month N
# 1: 2015-09 5
# 2: 2015-08 4
# 3: 2015-07 7
# 4: 2015-06 4
```

Or with base R's `aggregate()`

```
aggregate(list(N = df$y), list(month = format(df$x, "%Y-%m")), length)
#     month N
# 1 2015-06 4
# 2 2015-07 7
# 3 2015-08 4
# 4 2015-09 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a different approach using `group_by`. I also use `lubridate` to set POSIX date objects if you're interested.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

# create some data
data <- data.frame("dates" = ymd(c("2014-05-01","2014-05-01","2014-05-01","2014-06-02","2014-06-02")), 
                   "values" = c(1,3,5,2,5))

# this is the actual summarize. 
data %>% group_by(dates) %>% summarise(n = n())
```

yields

```
       dates     n
      (time) (int)
1 2014-05-01     3
2 2014-06-02     2
```